# How to add extra line separators on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I add again the extra line separators on a `UITableView`?

For example, I removed the extra line separators like this:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

to show an `UITableViewCell` saying the list is empty or an error has ocurred.

But when I retrieve items to the `UITableView` I want to show the extra lines again.

Is any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the footer view:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = nil
```